# vBulletin Rewrite rule on Nginx

Tags: vbulletin

I have link
`www.example.com/vb/?t=334158`
want rewrite it to
`http://www.example.com/vb/showthread.php?t=334158`
used all of this
`rewrite ^/vb/?t=([0-9]+) /vb/showthread.php?t=$1 permanent;`
`rewrite ^/vb/\?t=([0-9]+) /vb/showthread.php?t=$1 permanent;`
but its not working